# Magento XML AddJs - Add Parameters before src

Tags: javascript, xml, magento, cloudflare

In local.xml I need to add this parameter to prevent Cloudflare Rocket Loader from running on a particular script.

```
<params>data-cfasync="false"</params>
```

At the minute I have it like this:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.js</name><params>data-cfasync="false"</params></action>
```

Which works, however it adds it after the scripts' src. It needs to be placed before the src for Cloudflare to recognise it. Is there any way to do this.

I have tried adding it inbetween the first 'action' tag and the 'type' tag. As well as inbetween the '/type' tag and the 'name' tag. Neither of which work.

Answer (score 2):

Some changes need to be made to /app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php . It's wrong to make changes in core files so it would be better if you copy this file to /app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php and make all the changes in this new file.

Firstly, find line 210 (for Magento 1.9).

Then replace this:

```
$html .= $this->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<script type="text/javascript" src="%s"%s></script>' . "\n",
```

With this:

```
$html .= $this->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<script type="text/javascript"%s src="%s"></script>' . "\n",
```

Secondly, go to line 285 and replace this:

```
$html .= sprintf($format, $src, $params);
```

With this:

```
if (strpos($format, 'text/javascript')) {
    $html .= sprintf($format, $params, $src);
} else {
    $html .= sprintf($format, $src, $params);
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This definitely looks right, but unfortunately it just white screened the website. I'll keep looking into it, the site is 1.6.2.0, so that's probably why. Although the lines content is the same, just on 205 and 274 instead of 210 and 285.